# How do I install a python package if it already have Pip and the library downloaded?

Tags: python, installation

I downloaded Python 2.7 package from Git and saved it to the 'site-packages' folder as I normally do. I made sure I has Pip installed, but when I went to the CMD prompt to install using:

```
pip install hermes-python
```

I get this error:

Collecting hermes-python
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hermes-python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for hermes-python

Comment: Have you tried to update pip before trying this install?  pip install --upgrade pip  (or some variation based on your OS).

Comment: Just verified: "Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\arcgis10.6\lib\site-packages (19.1.1)". Ran again, still same error

Comment: Have you looked at this?   What platform are you on?https://hermespython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/requirements.html

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. I have no clue what 'if using other platform, build from source' means.

Comment: Ah yes, CMD almost gave you away.  It doesn't look like Windows is among the supported platforms for a pip install so you'll have to build it.  Sometimes 'building from source' is really easy and sometimes it can be a "rabbit hole" but will probably be a learning experience either way.  One hint is that you will need to have a compiler installed on your machine.  Do a little google searching about how to build python modules from source and then follow the instructions at the hermespython page.  https://hermespython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: Thank you! I will try that.